Couldn't install pylab in Pycharm
After entering this in terminal:
**pip install pylab  **
*the response of the terminal was
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pylab (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pylab*

**Now when i tried this :
pip install scikit-learn==0.23.1**

**the response of the Terminal was:**
*
Collecting scikit-learn==0.23.1
  Downloading scikit-learn-0.23.1.tar.gz (7.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7.2/7.2 MB 326.1 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [331 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX" and platform_python_implementation != "CPython"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools
        Downloading setuptools-69.5.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.2 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Downloading wheel-0.43.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
      Collecting Cython>=0.28.5
        Downloading Cython-3.0.10-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
      Collecting numpy==1.17.3
        Downloading numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4 MB)
           ---------------------------------------- 6.4/6.4 MB 309.2 kB/s eta 0:00:00
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting scipy>=0.19.1
        Downloading scipy-1.13.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 60.6/60.6 kB 457.6 kB/s eta 0:00:00
      INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of scipy to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while. 
        Downloading scipy-1.12.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 60.4/60.4 kB 456.4 kB/s eta 0:00:00
        Downloading scipy-1.11.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 60.4/60.4 kB 139.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00
        Downloading scipy-1.11.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 60.4/60.4 kB 266.8 kB/s eta 0:00:00
        Downloading scipy-1.11.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (59 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 59.1/59.1 kB 313.2 kB/s eta 0:00:00
        Downloading scipy-1.11.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (59 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 59.1/59.1 kB 240.9 kB/s eta 0:00:00
        Downloading scipy-1.10.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (58 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 59.0/59.0 kB 443.1 kB/s eta 0:00:00
        Downloading scipy-1.10.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (58 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 58.9/58.9 kB 311.9 kB/s eta 0:00:00
      INFO: pip is still looking at multiple versions of scipy to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
        Downloading scipy-1.9.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (58 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 58.5/58.5 kB 385.9 kB/s eta 0:00:00
        Downloading scipy-1.9.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (58 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 58.5/58.5 kB 438.5 kB/s eta 0:00:00
        Downloading scipy-1.9.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
        Downloading scipy-1.9.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
        Downloading scipy-1.8.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
      Downloading setuptools-69.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (893 kB)
         -------------------------------------- 893.7/893.7 kB 279.9 kB/s eta 0:00:00
      Downloading wheel-0.43.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
         ---------------------------------------- 65.8/65.8 kB 393.9 kB/s eta 0:00:00
      Downloading Cython-3.0.10-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.8 MB)
         ---------------------------------------- 2.8/2.8 MB 331.3 kB/s eta 0:00:00
      Downloading scipy-1.8.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (36.9 MB)
         ---------------------------------------- 36.9/36.9 MB 338.6 kB/s eta 0:00:00
      Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
        Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): started
        Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [244 lines of output]
        Running from numpy source directory.
        blas_opt_info:
        blas_mkl_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\raiad\\PycharmProjects\\ML_lab\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        blis_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\raiad\\PycharmProjects\\ML_lab\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\raiad\\PycharmProjects\\ML_lab\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'  
        customize GnuFCompiler
        Could not locate executable g77
        Could not locate executable f77
        customize IntelVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable ifort
        Could not locate executable ifl
        customize AbsoftFCompiler
        Could not locate executable f90
        customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable DF
        customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable efl
        customize Gnu95FCompiler
        Could not locate executable gfortran
        Could not locate executable f95
        customize G95FCompiler
        Could not locate executable g95
        customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
        customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
        Could not locate executable efort
        Could not locate executable efc
        customize PGroupFlangCompiler
        Could not locate executable flang
        don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\raiad\\PycharmProjects\\ML_lab\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_blas_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\raiad\\PycharmProjects\\ML_lab\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\raiad\\PycharmProjects\\ML_lab\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_blas_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\raiad\\PycharmProjects\\ML_lab\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        accelerate_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Users\raiad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fb1mhujn\numpy_a043ed5560704a4dadf3c2bcc0ed7792\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
            Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
            Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
            A better performance should be easily gained by switching
            Blas library.
          self.calc_info()
        blas_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\raiad\\PycharmProjects\\ML_lab\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Users\raiad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fb1mhujn\numpy_a043ed5560704a4dadf3c2bcc0ed7792\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
            the BLAS environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
        blas_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Users\raiad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fb1mhujn\numpy_a043ed5560704a4dadf3c2bcc0ed7792\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
            the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
          self.calc_info()
          NOT AVAILABLE

        'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
        operable program or batch file.
        non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
        lapack_opt_info:
        lapack_mkl_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\raiad\\PycharmProjects\\ML_lab\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_lapack_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\raiad\\PycharmProjects\\ML_lab\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_clapack_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\raiad\\PycharmProjects\\ML_lab\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        flame_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\raiad\\PycharmProjects\\ML_lab\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\raiad\PycharmProjects\ML_lab\.venv\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\raiad\PycharmProjects\ML_lab\.venv\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\raiad\PycharmProjects\ML_lab\.venv\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\raiad\PycharmProjects\ML_lab\.venv\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\raiad\PycharmProjects\ML_lab\.venv\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\raiad\PycharmProjects\ML_lab\.venv\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\raiad\PycharmProjects\ML_lab\.venv\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\raiad\PycharmProjects\ML_lab\.venv\lib
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        lapack_info:
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\raiad\\PycharmProjects\\ML_lab\\.venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Users\raiad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fb1mhujn\numpy_a043ed5560704a4dadf3c2bcc0ed7792\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
            the LAPACK environment variable.
          if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
        lapack_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Users\raiad\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fb1mhujn\numpy_a043ed5560704a4dadf3c2bcc0ed7792\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
            the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
          if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
          NOT AVAILABLE

        C:\Users\raiad\PycharmProjects\ML_lab\.venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:265: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
          warnings.warn(msg)
        running bdist_wheel
        running build
        running config_cc
        unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
        running config_fc
        unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
        running build_src
        build_src
        building py_modules sources
        creating build
        creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9
        creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy
        creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\distutils
        building library "npymath" sources
        No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
        Running setup.py clean for numpy
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        python setup.py clean did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [10 lines of output]
        Running from numpy source directory.

        `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

          - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
          - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                              files that aren't checked into the git repo)

        Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).

        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
      Failed to build numpy
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
      [end of output]

  note: This error originat*es from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

.....
# **I was expecting anything like:
# when i was installing matplotlib**
*Installing collected packages: pyparsing, pillow, kiwisolver, importlib-resources, fonttools, cycler, contourpy, matplotlib
Successfully installed contourpy-1.2.1 cycler-0.12.1 fonttools-4.51.0 importlib-resources-6.4.0 kiwisolver-1.4.5 matplotlib-3.8.4 pillow-10.3.0 pyparsing-3.1.2*


pylab is obsolete. You can directly use matplotlib with pyplot.

If you have installed Matplotlib then you already have pylab, but its use is no longer recommended.  The version of scikit-learn you are requesting is 4 years old so it’s unlikely you can install it in the same environment as the latest Matplotlib.

Does this answer your question? How to import 'cluster' and 'pylab' into Pycharm
